# What's the difference between push_back({ "George", 1 }) and push_back(Student("Jack", 10));

Tags: c++, c++11, object-construction, aggregate-type

I was just wondering if there's a difference between the following two lines:

```
objStudents.push_back({ "George", 1 });
objStudents.push_back(Student("Jack", 10));
```

Is one way more efficient than the other? Or is it just a different syntax that completes the same task?

Comment: If you want to know if one is more efficient, compile both ways with optimization enabled and test them.

Comment: I didn't even know that was a thing.

Comment: The difference is the first one pushes "George", the other "Jack" :) What would really help to answer the question is a [mcve] - a complete, short program that we can compile and run.

Comment: Though the code isn't identical, there are only minor differences: [Test on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/3d974r). I would consider this as less to be concerned about performance...

Comment: Should be using `emplace_back()` instead.

Comment: I've never even heard of emplace_back()...

Comment: @GeorgeAustinBradley: `emplaceXXX()` methods don't take a constructed object, but rather - arguments for construction, and construct the object in-place within the container.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assumming `Student` has a constructor with the right arguments, the difference is that while `objStudents.push_back(Student("Jack", 10));` always compiles,
`objStudents.push_back({ "George", 1 });` only compiles if the constructor is not declared `explicit`. On the other hand, if `Student` is an aggregate (e.g. `struct Student { string s; int i; };`), then only `objStudents.push_back({ "George", 1 });` compiles.

Both forms are equally efficient if they compile - both construct `Student` from e.g. `"George", 1` followed by invoking move (if exists) or copy constructor.

In the case with a constructor, a more efficient form, which compiles even if the constructor is `explicit`, is `objStudents.emplace_back("George", 1);`, which constructs `Student` directly inside the vector and avoids the extra move or copy. Of course, "more efficient" here is theoretical - a compiler may be able to optimize away the extra operation in the form with `push_back`.

Comment: I realized I missed the case of aggregates - added it now.